# Finding 6 angles for UR5 a 6Dof Robot

Tags: inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics, python, matrix

I am looking for a method to find 6 rotation angles for the 6DOF, 6joint, 5 link UR5 robot. these angles would be used to control UR5 through ROS but unfortunately I cant find any way to find these angles. I have tried making its DH Matrix for base to end T0-6, but it becomes too complex after 3-4 matrix multiplication I cant Track it anymore.

I have T06, although it contains all the information of robot position and orientation but I do not exactly need that. I need the 6 angle which will drive my robot and provide it with rotation angle on each joint. Suppose a 6 joint(6DOF) robotic arm and you have to give specific angles for each of the joints from base to end effector in order for the robotic arm to move to a specific position. I need a way to extract those 6 angles form a given T06 matrix.

This is the link to a pdf explaining the inverse kinematics of UR5, please refer this: https://tianyusongcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/ur5_inverse_kinematics.pdf

Please advise a good and short solution or a method to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* umar anjum, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: It is unclear to me exactly what you are looking for.  Are you trying to do IK, where you input a desired end-effector pose and then get the joint angles for that configuration?  Or are you trying to build the Jacobian matrix so that you can input an end-effector velocity, and get the joint velocities to move in that direction?